# issue installing node-red-node-sqlite

Tags: sqlite, npm, node-red

I am trying to install a "node-red-node-sqlite" using node-red UI on a virtual machine that has proxy setting, it throws error message. I am able to install other nodes on VM.

i have installed python v2.7.6; nodejs v10.16.3; npm 6.9.0 ; nvm v1.1.7 on VM; I have similar setup on my desktop (npm v6.11.3) and it works fine; but on the VM which is in another data-center and has proxy setting, It node-sqlite installation failes

I am following the steps 
1. npm i --unsafe-perm node-red-node-sqlite
2. cd ~/.node-red
3. npm rebuild

## But step-1 given me error as given below

PS C:\Users\userid.node-red> **npm i --unsafe-perm
    node-red-node-sqlite**

```
> sqlite3@4.1.0 install C:\Users\userid\.node-red\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for
sqlite3@4.1.0 and node@10.16.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back
to source compile with node-gyp) node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com
mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com:443 gyp WARN install got an
error, rolling back install gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack
Error: This is most likely not a problem with node-gyp or the
package itself and gyp ERR! stack is related to network
connectivity. In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad gyp
ERR! stack network settings. gyp ERR! stack     at
Request.<anonymous>
(C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.16.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:197:21) gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:198:13) gyp ERR! stack
at Request.onRequestError
(C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.16.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:881:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13) gyp ERR!
stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13) gyp ERR!
stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8) gyp ERR!
stack     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback
(internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT
10.0.14393 gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\ProgramData\\nvm\\v10.16.3\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build"
"--module=C:\\Users\\userid\\.node-red\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v64-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node"
"--module_name=node_sqlite3"
"--module_path=C:\\Users\\userid\\.node-red\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v64-win32-x64"
"--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0"
"--node_napi_label=node-v64" gyp ERR! cwd
C:\Users\userid\.node-red\node_modules\sqlite3 gyp ERR! node -v
v10.16.3 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok node-pre-gyp
ERR! build error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.16.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
configure --fallback-to-build
--module=C:\Users\userid\.node-red\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v64-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node
--module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\userid\.node-red\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v64-win32-x64
--napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
(C:\Users\userid\.node-red\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
(internal/child_process.js:982:16) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at
Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
(internal/child_process.js:259:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! System
Windows_NT 10.0.14393 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program
Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
"C:\\Users\\userid\\.node-red\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp"
"install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
C:\Users\userid\.node-red\node_modules\sqlite3 node-pre-gyp ERR!
node -v v10.16.3 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok Failed to execute 'C:\Program
Files\nodejs\node.exe
C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.16.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
configure --fallback-to-build
--module=C:\Users\userid\.node-red\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v64-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node
--module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\userid\.node-red\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v64-win32-x64
--napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! sqlite3@4.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install
--fallback-to-build` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.1.0 install script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
C:\Users\userid\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-21T15_57_41_109Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\userid\.node-red>
```

=======================
When I try to install the **"npm install --global --production windows-build-tools"** I get error =>

```
4115 verbose stack Error: windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall: `node ./dist/index.js`
4115 verbose stack Exit status 1
4115 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.16.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
4115 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
4115 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.16.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
4115 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
4115 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
4115 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
4116 verbose pkgid windows-build-tools@5.2.2
4117 verbose cwd C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0
```

Comment: This is problem building the native component of the` sqlite3` node (a dependency of `node-red-node-sqlite`). Do you have a required build tools installed to allow npm to build native modules?

Comment: i have installed  python v2.7.6; nodejs v10.16.3; npm 6.11.3 ; nvm;  I have similar setup on my desktop and it works fine; but on the VM which is in another datacenter and has proxy setting, It failes.

Comment: Fine, but what about a c++ compiler?

Comment: Try installing https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools

Comment: Downloading vs_BuildTools.exe
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND download.visualstudio.microsoft.com download.visualstudio.microsoft.com:443
Downloading Visual Studio Build Tools failed. Error: { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND download.visualstudio.microsoft.com download.visualstudio.microsoft.com:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'download.visualstudio.microsoft.com',
  host: 'download.visualstudio.microsoft.com',
  port: 443 }
windows-build-tools will now exit.

Comment: Those errors imply that your VM has network or DNS problems. "ENOTFOUND" means it can not resolve `download.visualstudio.microsoft.com`